# Sunspot search for User

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sunspot

I use sunspot for my application. In my application, people can upload sounds in his account and i use sunspot for research the name of the sounds. But my search found all sounds and not only the user sounds.

In my controller i wrote that :

```
if params[:search].present?
    @search = Sunspot.search(Sound) do
      fulltext params[:search]


    end

    @sounds = @search.results
  else
    @sounds = Sound.order(:title).all
  end

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # index.html.erb
    format.json { render json: @sounds }
  end
```

But that list all of my Sounds not only the user's sound.

I hope i was clear in my request.

Thank's for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In sunspot we have :with argument there we can pass your own filter like

```
Sounds.search do
  fulltext 'your text'
  with :user_id, 1
end
```

or

```
if params[:search].present?
  @search = Sunspot.search(Sound) do
  fulltext params[:search]
end
  @sounds = @search.results
else
  @sounds = Sound.order(:title).all
end
respond_to do |format|
  format.html # index.html.erb
format.json { render json: @sounds }
end
```

anyway @sounds having all the values so you could write one scope by_user and you can easily filter it.

like `@sounds.by_user(@user.id)`

more information please refer [Railcast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/278-search-with-sunspot),[Github](https://github.com/sunspot/sunspot),[sunspot.github.io](http://sunspot.github.io/)